# JNDI in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, jndi

Does SpringBoot use JNDI for the data base connection (auto configuration) ?

Can you give sample use cases which requires JNDI implementation in Spring Boot Application ?

Answer (score 0):

JNDI is very useful when the servlet container or the application server provides some resources to the application.

The usual example is the datasource. It is useful, because binding the datasource to the JNDI allows you to deploy the same application into different environments without changing any configuration file.